# {field:register_member}

Tags: expresso-store

I wonder where the {field:register_member} can be translated? 
I've looked through the Store lang file, but it does not seam to be translatable?

I have store 1.6.3 and EE 2.5.5.

cheers
stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it needs to be translated. All it does is output a hidden field to a page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="register_member" value="1" />
```

So the user wont actually see it anyway.

Comment: OMG! you are absolutely right. I just saw now that I've copied the english text and I've thought it was a label for the checkbox generated automatically. sorry, my bad - I guess I was working too much :)